# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection issue

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, java-8, oracle12c

I am having plain JDBC code with me which was written in 2005. The code which was working against all oracle database versions 9i, 10g, 11g but facing issues in oracle 12c. I am not facing this issue regularly but happening frequently (twice in a week). when i rerun my job, i am able to complete it successfully.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatementInternal(PhysicalConnection.java:1994)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:1960)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:1866)
        at com.venkat.Table.getType(TypeTable.java:69)
```

My TypeTable.java - line 63 to 69 is:

```
63 if (p_Connection == null)
64      {
65          String errorMsg = "Connection Object passed is null";
66          m_logger.debug(errorMsg);
67          throw new  IllegalArgumentException(errorMsg);
68      } 
69 p_Connection.prepareStatement(SQL_GET_RIO_TYPE);
```

I am with this issue since i move to oracle 12c. Please help me with the way to come out of this issue.

Comment: Your best bet would be to use a proper connection pool that would handle dropped connections. Or just check that the connection isn't closed before you use it.

Comment: I suppose you updated the JDBC driver too?

Comment: @Kayaman: I am not using connection and i am using the same code whatever i used in older versions.

Comment: @Aris: I updated JDBC driver too and i am using ojdb7.jar now